My discord bot keeps getting rate limited
My bot is supposed to fetch all the messages in a specific channel and time period and add them to a list. However, it constantly gets rate limited while it is fetching the messages.
for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
    async for message in channel.history(limit=None, before=to_date, after=start_message, oldest_first=True):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
        messages_to_mimic.append({
            "content": messagecontent,
            "attachments": attachments,
            "author_name": display_name,
            "author_avatar": avatar_url,
            "channel_name": channel.name,
            "original_channel_id": channel.id,
            "timestamp": message.created_at,
            "user_id": user_id,
            "message_id": message.id
        })

I was expecting the bot to fetch the messages as it intended, but instead it stops in the middle and spams "We have been rate limited!" in the terminal. I've tried adding a delay between getting each message, using parameters to make the message pool smaller, error handling rate limits, and limiting the message fetching to only the channels needed. None of these efforts worked.

I shortened the question if that helps

How many message are you fetching, and how often are you running this?

@TimRoberts I run it once and it fetches around 900 messages

And do you understand that Discord has a limit of 50 requests per second?  It returns the limit to you in the request headers.  You will have to fetch the messages in smaller batches and wait.

@TimRoberts i thought the 0.03 second sleep would account for that
